# LibreOffice won't open on Fedora 27

Tags: fedora, libreoffice

If I've tried to open a file I've got splash screen with loader and it disappear. If I run it from terminal I've got output:

```
Application Error
```

if I run

```
libreoffice --writer
```

I don't get any output, just the splash screen and for a split of second small window with black background.

I've searched but only found [issue with Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/643382/libre-office-wont-open), I've deleted .config/libreoffice but that didn't solve the issue.

Other problem found with [shared library](https://forum.openoffice.org/en/forum/viewtopic.php?f=16&t=91704). It was for OpenOffice, but even that I've check this:

```
find /usr/lib64/libreoffice -name "*.so" | xargs ldd -v | grep found
```

and it din't found anything.

Does anyone know how to solve the issue with LibreOffice on Fedora 27? Or how to get more info on actual error instead of just `Application Error`?

Comment: Fill a [bugreport](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/How_to_file_a_bug_report)

Comment: @IporSircer thanks, added https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1608996